# Cosmos : Get all items from a partition in a container in c# / .Net #CosmosClient

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I created a container to store user information for customers. The partitionKey is customerId.  I want to read all items in a logical partition with customerId = X, that should return all user records with customerId = X. Is such an API available in CosmosClient in .NET SDK?

Example :

```
class User
{
      string customerId,
      string userId,
      string userName
}
```

Comment: Please be mindful of tags - I removed several unrelated tags (e.g. `cosmos` has nothing to do with Cosmos DB, nor does `containers`). As far as additional info needed when you edit your question: Please show a bit of example data, your query/code, output, and errors/issues you're encoutering.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are using SQL API, you can use [Azure Cosmos DB SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet-standard) to fetch all the Users for your partition key. Here is the sample code:

```
var client = new CosmosClient("COSMOS_CONNECTION_STRING");
var container = client.GetContainer("DATABASE_NAME", "CONTAINER_NAME");
var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c");
var iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<User>(queryDefinition,
            requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
            {
                PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("CUSTOMER_ID")                                                                      
            });

var results = new List<User>();

while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
{
     var result = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();
     results.AddRange(result.Resource);
}

return results;
```

Comment: Note that the OP's question, as written, is off-topic: it contains no code, output, or specific issues; it was a general requirement, and I suggested what they needed to add, in my comments. Best not to just write code for someone when they haven't presented their own work first.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon, thanks for your response. The reason I responded to this question is because I felt getting all the documents for a partition key can be a bit tricky specially for starters. Given that I have already responded to the question what do you suggest I should do?